# How much time does it take for a TSNE Plot or any other plot to run?

Tags: pandas, data-visualization, visualization

I am using the amazon food reviews data set and trying to do a TSNE plot. It is taking a lot of time to run. I am using only 5000 rows in the data set and also i am trying to run it in google colab.

It has been running for the past half an hour and no output yet.

Any one knows how much time it takes to run?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing what the data looks like or what you're running on.
I understand that you're working with some big data. I encourage you to take a look at this function i found. The link below explains how it works. 
credit for this function is here: 
[credit](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-in-pandas/)

```
def reduce_mem_usage(df):
    start_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
    print('Memory usage of dataframe is {:.2f} MB'.format(start_mem))

    for col in df.columns:
        col_type = df[col].dtype
    if col_type != object:
            c_min = df[col].min()
            c_max = df[col].max()
            if str(col_type)[:3] == 'int':
                if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint32)                    
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int64)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint64)
            else:
                if c_min > np.finfo(np.float16).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
                elif c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
                else:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float64)

    end_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
    print('Memory usage after optimization is: {:.2f} MB'.format(end_mem))
    print('Decreased by {:.1f}%'.format(100 * (start_mem - end_mem) / start_mem))
return df
```

This will make sure your dataframe use as low memory as possible when you're working with it.